# Use AJAX to retrieve a record from a database with user input

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Platform: Google App Engine (Python)
Database: Google Cloud SQL

I basically have a simple webpage with a sidebar and a main view. The sidebar basically consists of a set of records from a database and when I click on one of them, I want more detailed information to be pulled from the database and displayed in the main view.

I tried using def get(self) in the handler, but the variable is not being read. Is it possible to use self.request.get('variable') in a def get(self)? Is there otherwise any way to pass a variable from a def post(self) to a def get(self)?

Below is most of the code that I am using. Apart from the code below, I am passing the results out to a template, which is then fetched once more using AJAX. That part works as expected.

**// HTML code**

```
<table class="query-results user">
<tbody>
{% autoescape on %}
{% for row in user_queries %}
<tr class="query-results">
  <td class="query-user">
    <img class="query-user-avatar" src="../img/avatars/{{ row.1 }}_32x32x32.png"><br />
  </td>
  <td class="query-main" data-queryid="{{ row.8 }}">
    <span class="query-title">{{ row.2 }}</span><br />{{ row.3 }}</br>{{ row.0 }} || {{ row.5 }} ago
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endautoescape %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

**// AJAX - send variable to QueryTab Handler:**

```
$("td.query-main").live('click', function(){
  var queryid = $(this).data("queryid");
    var dataString = 'queryId='+ queryid;
    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",  
      url: "/querytab",  
      data: dataString,
      success: function () { alert("data sent: " + dataString) }
      });  
    return false;
});
```

**Python Code:**

```
class QueryTab(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    query_id = self.request.get('queryId')

    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    conn = rdbms.connect(instance=_INSTANCE_NAME, database='userPrefs')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT q.userNickname, a.avatar, q.queryName, q.queryDescription, q.queryValue, q.dateCreated, q.dateLastUpdated, q.activeFlag, q.uniqueId, q.entryID FROM queries AS q LEFT JOIN avatarPrefs AS a ON q.userNickname = a.userNickname WHERE q.activeFlag ="true" AND q.uniqueId = %s ORDER BY q.dateLastUpdated DESC LIMIT 6', (query_id))
    self_query = [[str(row[0]), str(row[1]), str(row[2]), str(row[3]), str(row[4]), str(timesince(datetime.strptime(str(row[5]), fmt))), str(timesince(datetime.strptime(str(row[6]), fmt))), str(row[7]), str(row[8]), str(row[9])] for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    template_file_name = 'templates/querytab.html'
    template_values = {
      'self_query': self_query,
      'query_id': query_id,
    }

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), template_file_name)
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Put some debugging in to see where it's going wrong. Is the Ajax correctly getting the queryid from the DOM? Is it correctly sending it in the request? Does the Python see anything in request.get? etc.

Comment: I added some debugging logs and it seems that the queryId is correctly received. The query also worked (using logging.info I was able to retrieve the values). However, strangely enough, the template can't pick them up for some reason, and throws back the following message at me: `query_info = self_query[0]
IndexError: list index out of range` which is strange as the logging.info didn't have any issues understanding this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time, I wasn't as adept yet with AJAX, so didn't quite understand the callback functionality. What I ended up using was something along the lines of:

```
$('td.query-main').live('click', function() {
  var queryid = $(this).data("queryid");
  var dataString = 'term=' + queryid;
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/snippets",  
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#query-focus').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```